# Power MOSFET boards without capacitors?

Tags: mosfet, capacitor, decoupling-capacitor, powermosfet

[image]

I'm seeing a bunch of power MOSFET boards that don't have any capacitors. How are they supposed to work without capacitors to deal with voltage dropout?

Comment: What exactly is this board supposed to *do*?

Comment: Looks like just a breakout board. Well, a few resistors and an indicator LED. There's no logic or control on there; what would you expect a capacitor to do?

Comment: It's an example of a power mosfet board breakout.  I guess I'm not sure how power mosfet works I'm wondering if it's something that needs a cap or not?  If it's called power mosfet but not really driving high current or voltage then maybe it doesn't matter.

Comment: How would a capacitor help against voltage dropout in the first place?

Comment: I found one of these units here: https://www.elecbee.com/en-31651-Geekcreitreg-MOS-Trigger-Switch-Driver-Module-FET-PWM-Regulator-High-Power-Electronic-Switch-Control?utm_term=&utm_campaign=shopping_%E7%BE%8E%E5%9B%BD2021/03/05&utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=ppc&hsa_acc=9958698819&hsa_cam=12473735731&hsa_grp=115457242501&hsa_ad=502747062194&hsa_src=s&hsa_tgt=pla-1186173532455&hsa_kw=&hsa_mt=&hsa_net=adwords&hsa_ver=3&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIsdTpnqOJ_AIVCuTICh1AiAlZEAQYAiABEgLi6fD_BwE. But there is no schematic, and I'm not sure how it is supposed to work. Are the MOSFETs in parallel?

Comment: The hookup image https://www.elecbee.com/image/catalog/Driver-Module/Geekcreitreg-MOS-Trigger-Switch-Driver-Module-FET-PWM-Regulator-High-Power-Electronic-Switch-Control-1237874-descriptionImage0.jpeg shows the PWM or OFF/ON signal on J1, and the other terminals are labeled Input + and -, and out + and -. shown as a switch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MOSFETs don't need a capacitor to function properly.  Simplified description: they are constructed of a "source" area and a "drain" area separated by a normally non-conductive channel.  A "gate" terminal sits above the channel and is insulated from the rest of the device by a thin oxide layer.  By adjusting the voltage on the gate relative to the source, a conductive pathway between the source and drain can be created, which allows current to flow from the source to the drain (P-channel type devices) or from the drain to the source (N-channel type devices).

Which leads to your question "do you need capacitors on this board?"  While capacitors are generally useful when switching to prevent voltage sag from the step change in current, they are most useful at the point of load to minimize the inductance and resistance of the intervening wiring.  Putting the capacitors on the board would not accomplish this.  Furthermore, the capacitor selection (voltage rating, capacitance, construction, material, etc) are all dependent on the load, so it wouldn't make much sense to make the board bigger and more expensive with capacitors that may not be appropriate for the application.  Finally, capacitors on power rails go between the rail and ground; the N-channel MOSFETs on this board are almost certainly going to be connected for low-side switching (between ground and the - terminal of the load) so there's no place to attach a capacitor to the power rail.

Comment: This looks like a half bridge used for PWM.  Sure, it may work without any decoupling capacitors.  But radiated and conducted EMI will probably be greatly reduced by having some small capacitors right next to the FETs.

Comment: Looking into this more, at least in my use case, a power mosfet replaces an electromechanical relay.  I agree, in the context of a drop-in replacement for an electromagnetic relay, caps on the mosfet board don't necessarily make sense.